# how to make a select query in progress openedge procedure editor

Tags: openedge

Hello I want to make a select statement in openedge procedure eduitor

and as I'm so so new to Propgress and everything is so strange to me having in mind that I have only wirked with MSSQL and 
.
SO Suppose I have  an articlegroup table

1. First how to see all records from all the fields of this table -  `Select * from articlegroup`
2. Then how to add a where clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderfully different world of OpenEdge :)

```
FOR EACH articlegroup Where whereClauseGoeshere:
    /*do what you want with the record buffer*/
    DISPLAY articlegroup.
END.
```

here is a place for you to start with:
http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge102b/pdfs/gsabl/gsabl.pdf

Comment: OpenEdge is very powerful when it comes to handling database operations but you need to do it the ABL way :) which is very different from SQL. However you should know that you can issue SQL queries to a progress database.

Comment: While it is sort of possible to use some limited embedded SQL statements like SELECT from within a 4GL session it is a very bad idea to do so.  The embedded SQL is SQL-89 and it is very limited.  It was put there to satisfy marketing checkboxes -- not as a primary means of accessing data.  You will only find, frustration, pain and agony by trying to treat a 4GL session as SQL.  Progress is NOT SQL and trying to pretend that it is is an exercise in futility.